# Using Vocal Rider with Cubase and/or Audacity

Tags: voice, mixing, audacity, cubase, mastering

I use Cubase Elements and purchased **Vocal Rider**.

After installing and activating Vocal Rider, I couldn't find it as a standalone program in start up.

I tried to understand if it's possible to use **Vocal Rider** with Cubase audio record and/or Audacity, I couldn't find any hint.

Would you provide helpful information?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean [Waves Vocal Rider](https://www.waves.com/plugins/vocal-rider#image)?

[image]

It installs as a VST plugin, it's not a standalone app.
Use it as an Insert on the vox channel [or group if you're comping channels].

Cubase comes with its own comprehensive manual.
Audacity instructions for plugins - https://www.audacityteam.org/download/plug-ins/